# Cursor - Android

Tags: android, cursor

Is it possible to use 2 different cursors for selecting table :

this for a table1

```
Cursor b = myDbHelper.getSchoolType();
String def = b.getString(0);
```

and this for another table

```
c = myDbHelper.getAllSchoolData();
String abc = c.getString(0);
```

I try to retrieve data from two table useing two cursor but it show error :

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException : Index -1 requested, with a size of 2
```

please help...
thanks for all kinds of answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the cursor pointer points to the position before the first entry (row), so you need to move it to a proper position before you can read data from it. For example move to the first entry:

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) 
    String value = cursor.getString(0);
    ...
}
```

There are similar methods like moveToNext(), moveToLast() etc, see the [reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) for more.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it or not. If in your code b and c are two Cursor objects they should be independent to each other, so you should check them for null and move their cursor pointer respectively.

Comment: I mean definitely you can have two Cursor objects that are created by two query operations from two different tables, then you should check them against null and move their cursor pointers respectively like this before you can read data from them: "if (b!=null&&b.moveToFirst()) {// here you can get data from b}" and "if (c!=null&&c.moveToFirst()) {// here you can get data from c}".

Comment: @Zitheng Chen : and the error said 
 **Index -1 requested, with a size of 7**

Comment: Did you follow my advice and call moveToFirst() before reading data from any of your cursors by getString()?

Comment: I read the error message "Index -1 requested, with a size of 7" like this: the cursor has 7 entries, and they are indexed from 0 to 6, however the cursor pointer is still in its initial position (-1, the one before the first entry), so it is impossible to get any valid data. To fix the issue you should really call a proper moveToXXX method, usually moveToFirst() then moveToNext() to handle the entries one by one, until the methods return false, which means no more entries left.

Comment: Yes, I do follow your advice but I don't know what's my problem : 
'if(b != null && b.moveToFirst())
          {
           do
           {
            item2.add(b.getString(0).toString());
           }while(b.moveToNext());
          }'....item2 is a ArrayList<String>

Comment: Good, I think it fixed the first error "Index -1 requested, with a size of 2", then go on handling your cursor c in the same way. i.e. "if(c!=null&c.moveToFirst()){// do something}", and that will fix the second error "Index -1 requested, with a size of 7".

Comment: that's work now  :) , thanks you so much......but please forgive me, I'm not yet have enough reputation to vote....

Comment: Glad to know I helped. 23:38 GMT+8, time to go to bed, good night!

Answer (score 0):

`Cursor` index is placed at -1 when retreived. You need to move it to first result. For this you have different choices, but this is how I use it:

```
Cursor c = // Retreive your cursor;
if (c != null) {
    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        // Code for each row
    }
}
```

This will loop over all cursor rows.

You should always read [Android tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#ReadDbRow) or examine the [SDK reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html). Learning to read documentation is a basic skill for a programmer.